# How to set a reminder(alarm) using eventKit framework for a particular date

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, eventkit, ekeventkit

I am working with EventKit framework in iOS 5 and I successfully added an event to the iOS calendar using the below code

```
EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];

    myEvent.title     = @"New Event";
    myEvent.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    myEvent.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    myEvent.allDay = YES;

    [myEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
```

Now How shall i added an alarm (reminder) for this event ?

Thanks
Ranjit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By Adding this code -

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 60* -min;
```

Where min is the time when you want to show alert. this should be a negative value so that this will appear (min) before of your event.

```
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:interval];
[myEvent addAlarm:alarm];
```

Enjoy!!!