# Want add reminder in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

I want to add reminder functionality in my iphone app, I came to know that I need to use local notification but I don't want to use it.

So is there any way to fulfill my need ??

Comment: Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: I have several requirements that reminder already has, thats why I want to use reminder instead of local notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use UILocal notification use EKEventStore for adding reminders in iPhone Calendar. You can add your alarm, events etc in iPhone Calendar.
But remember it supports only iOS 6.0 or later. you cannot change in iPhone calendar in lower iOS6.0 version

Follow these links:

[Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254614/how-to-set-time-in-alarm-using-eventkit-framework-in-ios-6) 
[Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270117/how-to-set-a-reminderalarm-using-eventkit-framework-for-a-particular-date)

Answer (score 1):

**UILocalNotification** is a nice thing but if you don't want to use it you can make use of **EventKit** that gives you access to device's reminders.

Create EventStore object with reminder type.

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityMaskReminder];
```

Get access from user.

```
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    // handle access here }];
```

use this function to create reminders

```
+ (EKReminder *)reminderWithEventStore:(EKEventStore *)eventStore
```

[Refer documentation for more details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html) .

Answer (score 1):

There is an another way, other than using the local notification, see my answer posted [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043069/how-to-set-reminder-in-ios-for-a-particular-time-and-show-it-after-2-min-interva/19043200#19043200) in this u set an event in the calendar and set the repeat settings by setting alarm.

Hope this helps you.